# forking in for loop with printf

Tags: loops, for-loop, printing, fork

actually I am new at forking concept and although similar questions are asked, I didnot understand a question. My question is here.

```
int main(void){
int i;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    if(fork()==0)
     printf("%d\n",5);

}
return 0;
}
```

the output is:
0
1
5
5
1
5
 I am confused with the output. I will be happy with your helps, thanks already

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
printf("%d\n", 5);
```

I imagine you meant to put i instead of 5 at the end of that printf. I'm not sure what result you're looking for, but i'd imagine that could be the source of your confusion.

Comment: I actually wrote this to work with forking but what I dont understand why we go back the first printf and print 1 again. child process starts from fork() am I right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its still going to execute the parent process, as well as the child process. it's alternating commands from each

Comment: i don't know a whole lot about C but i know a lot about java threads and that's how it works. you thread a process and they run concurrently

Comment: does that answer your question? I'm assuming that's what you were looking for. from my understanding, using the fork() call is threading a process, so the processes will run next to each other